# upload test cases from excel to microsoft test manager 2013

Tags: testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

In my current project we are using Microsoft Test Manager 2013. We have prepared test cases in excel. How can we upload prepared test cases from excel to MTM 2013.

Answer (score 2):

*Additionally to the answer by @MrHinsh:*

Check [Create Manual Tests using Team Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286729.aspx) and look for the question ***Can I copy test cases and test steps from an existing Excel worksheet?*** in the **Q&A** part.

Answer (score 0):

I do this using the free tool tcmimport: http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by copying and pasting into the test grid in the web access for TFS 2013. In the web access to to the test tab and for the test suit you want to add items to switch to grid mode. Then past in in the required format.

I recommend preparing test cases directly in Web Access or MTM. Your current workflow is a dysfunction resulting from Quality Centre use .