# How to add test cases to microsoft test manager through program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, testcase, microsoft-test-manager

I have a set of test cases in an excel file. I need to import it to microsoft test manager through a c# program/or some scripting languages. I searched web but most of the answers are pointing towards using "test case migrator plus". Also they are using test case migrator to import test cases from excel to TFS (team Foundation Server) and not to MTM. But I need it to be done through my program. Can i use test case migrator using a c# program? Or is there any way to add Test cases to MTM? Thank you for the help.
Also, i have checked posts similar to [upload test cases from excel to microsoft test manager 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605596/upload-test-cases-from-excel-to-microsoft-test-manager-2013) , but to me, they failed in addressing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TFS API to create test cases.  Here is some sample code from a [blog post](http://automatetheplanet.com/manage-tfs-test-cases-csharp-code/) which fully explains the process.

```
     ITestCase testCaseCore = testManagementTeamProject.TestCases.Create(); 
     currentTestCase = new TestCase(testCaseCore, sourceTestCase.ITestSuiteBase, testPlan); 

     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Area = sourceTestCase.Area; 
     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Title = sourceTestCase.Title; 
     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Priority = (int)sourceTestCase.Priority; 
     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Actions.Clear(); 
     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Owner = testManagementTeamProject.TfsIdentityStore.FindByTeamFoundationId(sourceTestCase.TeamFoundationId); 

     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Flush(); 
     currentTestCase.ITestCase.Save();
```

Comment: That helped me a lot !.. Thank you, the blog explains most of the required things. Thnak you again.